# puppet directory trees creation from a variable

Tags: puppet, recursive

Im trying to create directory tree using puppet. Ex
dir => /home/any_dirname/any_dirname2/any_dirname3/

Is it possible to create above tree in puppet where dirname can be anything so im taking it as a variable. How do i split the variable and ensure each directory is created?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this cannot work out of the box. See [this old feature request](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/86#note-40). It holds links to resources that may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much everybody writes his own mymodule::mkdirp{} resource :) . This is the solution. One example (not by me): echocat/nfs, the resource is called "mkdirp" I think.

Have fun writing your own ;)